# Is there an alternative solution to adding User.where(organisation_id: current_user.organisation_id) in each method in users_controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do this, because the applications will be used by multiple organizations. So I want each user to see only data corresponding to his organization I can add .where(organisation_id: current_user.organisations_id) in each method in each controller but this will be a lot of changes.
Is there a better solutions?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar more generic solution is using `accessible_by(current_ability)` from cancancan gem (or other authorisation gem solution like pundit etc.) to fine tune (under the hood it will do the same `where(organization...`):

ability.rb:

```
can :manage, SomeModelName, organization_id: user.organization_id
can :read, SomeOtherModel, user_id: user.id
```

this approach is better than hardcoding abilities in your code because when access rules change - you will not have to go through all your code again to change them.

Other way:
In fact, you can spare yourself changing all queries via `default_scope` and violating mvc principles by taking `current_user` to the model scope, but I advise against it - later this can become very hard to work with.